# 'wsimport' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, soap

There are a few of these questions. But my `PATH` variable is correct

```
;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

My `JAVA_HOME` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131`

When I type java -version, I get

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

`echo %JAVA_HOME%` and `echo %PATH%` return what they are supposed to. What can be the reason `wsimport` doesn't work?

My full `PATH` is

```
C:\Informatica\9.5.1\clients\DT\bin;C:\Informatica\9.5.1\clients\tools\datadirect;C:\Informatica\9.5.1\clients\tools\odbcdrv;C:\oracle\client_1\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ZOOKEEPER_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;
```

Comment: try giving full path of wsimport C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\wsimport

Comment: It is problem with your `%PATH%`. What is `echo %PATH%` output?

Comment: What does the command `where java` print?

Comment: @VGR It prints `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe`, but my jdk is actually in `Program Files`

Comment: @talex Added full PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%JAVA_HOME%\bin` won't work in `%PATH%`. It should be full path without variables. There is no variable expansion when OS search for executable.

Your `java` executable found in some system folder.

I suppose `%SystemRoot%` is some sort of special case.

**Solution**

Replace `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` by real path.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to check `javac -version`. Maybe you provide some wrong path for JDK and system recognize only JRE path.
What is `echo %PATH%` output? Is there some different path for java before `;%JAVA_HOME%\bin`?

Comment: Added full `PATH`